# Как найти сумму бесконечного ряда?

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Дано:[image: Бесконечный ряд]

Вот мой код:

```
//найти сумму бесконечного ряда
#include <iostream>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;
 int main() 
 {
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
     double long sum, eps, A,x,n;
     cout << "x="; cin >> x;
     cout << "eps="; cin >> eps;
     int i = 0;
     n = 5;
     A = 1 / 3.0;
     sum = A;
     cout << left << setw(3) << "i\t" << setw(10) << "a\t"; //заголовок
     cout << setw(10) << "S" << endl;
     cout << left << setw(3) << 1 << "\t" << setw(10) << A; //1 шаг
     cout << "\t" << setw(10) << sum << endl;

     for (int i = 2; abs(A) > eps && i <= n; i++) //i-ый шаг
     {
         A = A * x * x / (2 * i * (2 * i - 1));
     sum += A;
     cout << left << setw(3) << i << "\t" << setw(10) << A;
     cout << "\t" << setw(10) << sum << endl;
     }
     cout << "sum=" << sum << endl;
     return 0;
    
}
```

И прикладываю вывод дабы было понятно в чём ошибка:[image: Вывод]

Не идут у меня задачки с математикой сегодня...Можете помочь пожалуйста с исправлениями?

Comment: x лишний, у вас же не x^(2n)

Comment: @vp_arth,допустим я исправил эту строчку,но программа от этого лучше не стала:(

Comment: Почему же, стала) Осталось исправить начальные значения. Посчитайте член для n=0 и положите в A; `A = 1;`. А цикл запускайте с самого начала, с 1 с нулевой суммой: `sum = 0; for (int i = 1; ...`.

Comment: @vp_arth,хорошо исправил,но программа выводит две строчки вместо нужных пяти...Вот исправленные строчки :for (int i = 1; abs(A) > eps && i <= n; i++) //i-ый шаг
И вот ещё одна: n = 10;
  A = 1;
  S = 0;

Comment: Судя по обведённому заданию, вам нужно посчитать 4 разные суммы)

Comment: Т.е. просто повторите всё это ещё 3 раза) Можно выделить всё это в функцию)

Comment: @vp_arth,то здесь нужно ещё три цикла?

Comment: Да, с другими начальными данными. x, eps

Comment: vp_arth Хм,а как мне сделать всё это в функции main?Или делать наподобие как у Harry?double S(double x, double eps)

Comment: Да, именно это я имел в виду под «можно выделить всё это в функцию»

Comment: vp_arth,позже попробую переписать

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то все просто... :) x у вас везде положителен, так что...

```
double x;
cin >> x;
cout << cosh(sqrt(x))-1 << endl;
```

Ну, или

```
double x;
cin >> x;
x = exp(sqrt(x));
cout << (x+1/x)/2 - 1 << endl;
```

Ну, или если реально нужно посчитать ряд - то

```
double S(double x, double eps)
{
    double term = x/2, sum = term;
    for(int n = 2; abs(term) > eps; ++n)
        sum += term *= x/(2*n-1)/(2*n);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Harry,а можете дать верхнюю часть программы,вот этот кусок я вставил в свою программу,но у меня конфликтует остальная часть программы

Comment: Ну так что-то типа `cout << "x="; cin >> x;
     cout << "eps="; cin >> eps;
     cout << "sum=" << S(x,eps) << endl;`

Comment: Harry,окей,понял,подправлю:)